# Stored Procedure para inserção de dados de log

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Preciso criar uma Stored Procedure no meu banco SQL Server. O objetivo desse Stored Procedure é gravar dados em uma tabela Log, que possui três campos: data, hora, ID de quem fez login.

Data e hora seriam do momento do login, enquanto o ID de Login vem de uma tabela de logins. O site já possuirá o momento de chamar essa Stored Procedure no momento do login.

A grande dúvida é que código eu coloco na Stored Procedure, já que quase não trabalho com isso em SQL Server. Quem pode ajudar nessa?

Comment: você está com problemas de criar uma ou chamar na aplicação? Aqui tem um bom tutorial de como criar. http://imasters.com.br/artigo/223/sql-server/criacao-e-uso-de-stored-procedures

Comment: Pra criar mesmo. Na aplicação, já foi feita uma maneira de chamar a stored procedure.

Comment: Entendi, o tutorial que te passei ajuda bastante. Vale a pena da uma estudada nele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente você só precisa do seguinte.

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[sp_LogUsuario_Update]
  @IdUsuario int,
  @DtInclusao int
  -- se precisa de mais campo adicione aqui.
as
begin
  Set Xact_Abort on
  Set Nocount on
  Begin Tran

  begin
     -- informe os campos que você que inseri na sua tabela
    Insert into tb_LogUsuario( IdUsuario,  DtInclusao) values
     ( 
        --- aqui você passa seus campos caso a data seja a hora local user o GETDATE() , o tipo de campo  da tabela tem 
        -- que ser DAteTime
        @IdUsuario, @DtInclusao 
     )

  end

  Commit
end
GO
```

Altere o que for necessário de acordo com sua necessidade.

Comment: Perfeito!!! Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_LogUsuario]
(
  @id int,
  @data int
)

AS
BEGIN
---------
-- LOG --
---------
DECLARE @txtransacao VARCHAR(1000) = '@data=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), ISNULL(GETDATE(), '')) + ',@id=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), ISNULL(@id, 0))

INSERT INTO log_acaoUsuario (log_txmensagem)
VALUES (@txtransacao) -- TENS QUE CRIAR ESSA TABELA COM ESSA COLUNA (qualquer nome)

---------------
-- VARIÁVEIS --
---------------

------------------
-- PROCEDIMENTO --
------------------
```

Agora é só fazer

```
SELECT * FROM log_acaoUsuario
```

E está aí o log